# thread unarchiving with aws s3 and sqs

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can I kill a thread that is running from another service that is uploading to an s3 bucket? I want the thread to stop when it finishes unarchiving archive file types. How can I kill the thread to end when it is empty of these types of files, my s3 bucket is also reading from an sqs queue.

I am trying to kill a thread I have created with the start method from the Thread class.

I tried to use start from thread class.

Comment: Please explain what you are referring to as *"a thread that is running from another service."*

Comment: I am running an integration test to test the service is working properly, however when I call the service from the integration test, as a new thread the service doesn't end even when I put the flag. I am now getting a config error since my main method in the service gets the config env variables and also spins up another instance of running the thread